# How to convert one JSON object to another JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use the plugin below to render some Events Data from our sharepoint events list.
http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/

From that site I am using the inLine Json Example like this:

```
<div id="eventCalendarInline"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var eventsInline = [{ "date": "1414490400000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1414490400000", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },
                    { "date": "1414490400000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1338885237000", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },
                    { "date": "1414490400000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1414490400000", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },
                    { "date": "1344515447000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1345033847000", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },
                    { "date": "1347712247000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1348230647000", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },
                    { "date": "1349094647000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project A meeting", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },
                    { "date": "1351600247", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" }];

                $("#eventCalendarInline").eventCalendar({
                    jsonData: eventsInline,
                    openEventInNewWindow: true,
                    showDescription: true,
                    eventsScrollable: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see there are 4 fields:

1. Date
2. Type
3. Title
4. Description

That was the 'Events' hardcoded version.

Now my JS Code already returns the items also in JSON, and I need to convert it to the same format as above, and also the date should be converted to that format.

```
var SPHostUrl;
var SPAppWebUrl;
var ready = false;

// this function is executed when the page has finished loading. It performs two tasks:
//    1. It extracts the parameters from the url
//    2. It loads the request executor script from the host web
$(document).ready(function () {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
        switch (param[0]) {
            case "SPAppWebUrl":
                SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "SPHostUrl":
                SPHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
        }
    }

    // load the executor script, once completed set the ready variable to true so that
    // we can easily identify if the script has been loaded
    $.getScript(SPHostUrl + "/_Layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function (data) {
        ready = true;
        getItems();
    });
});

// this function retrieves the items within a list which is contained within the parent web
function getItems() {

    // only execute this function if the script has been loaded
    if (ready) {

        // the name of the list to interact with
        var listName = "Events";

        // the url to use for the REST call.
        var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +

            // this is the location of the item in the parent web. This is the line
            // you would need to change to add filters, query the site etc
            "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Title,Category,EventDate,Description" +
            "&@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

        // create  new executor passing it the url created previously
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(SPAppWebUrl);

        // execute the request, this is similar although not the same as a standard AJAX request
        executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    // parse the results into an object that you can use within javascript
                    var results = eval(JSON.parse(data.body));
                },
                error: function (data) {

                    // an error occured, the details can be found in the data object.
                    alert("Ooops an error occured");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

An screenshot of the JSON Returned is here:

http://screencast.com/t/KF6tBMDYrjS

JSON from sharepoint

```
{
   "d":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(1)",
               "uri":"http://apps-f5dd09fb663079.apps.com/MiniCalendar/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(1)",
               "etag":"\"1\"",
               "type":"SP.Data.EventsListItem"
            },
            "Title":"GTS Meeting",
            "EventDate":"2014-10-14T15:00:00Z",
            "Description":"&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
            "Category":"Meeting"
         },
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(2)",
               "uri":"http://apps-f5dd09fb663079.apps.com/MiniCalendar/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(2)",
               "etag":"\"1\"",
               "type":"SP.Data.EventsListItem"
            },
            "Title":"Event 2",
            "EventDate":"2014-10-21T10:00:00Z",
            "Description":null,
            "Category":null
         },
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(3)",
               "uri":"http://apps-f5dd09fb663079.apps.com/MiniCalendar/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(3)",
               "etag":"\"1\"",
               "type":"SP.Data.EventsListItem"
            },
            "Title":"Event3",
            "EventDate":"2014-10-29T09:00:00Z",
            "Description":"  dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa",
            "Category":null
         },
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(4)",
               "uri":"http://apps-f5dd09fb663079.apps.com/MiniCalendar/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f33a5776-235c-4187-a0de-4db747221854')/Items(4)",
               "etag":"\"1\"",
               "type":"SP.Data.EventsListItem"
            },
            "Title":"sad sadsa dsa das",
            "EventDate":"2014-10-22T09:00:00Z",
            "Description":" asdsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa dsa",
            "Category":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `eval(JSON.parse(data.body))`?? `JSON.parse(data.body)` should be enough; using `eval()` exposes you to all kinds of security risks.

Comment: I suggest to remove the large code block near the end and instead post the JSON which you get. You can use a formatting service like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to make it pretty.

Comment: I just found the code somewhere, not sure why they put eval.

Comment: @AaronDigulla just pasted the json returned by sharepoint

Comment: Try `console.log(data.body);` to see what the service sends you in the browser's JavaScript console. Maybe they really wrap the JSON twice or something.

Comment: sounds like you just want someone to do all the work for you. What have you tried that isn't working? There are 100's of posts on this site how to map data from one format to another

Comment: @charlietfl I dont even know how to do it that is the question.  check the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated way to convert the two objects. You need to write the code yourself:

Assuming you know how to iterate over the array in `result.d.results` in a variable `e`, you can create events like so:

```
var event = {
    type: e.Category.toLowercase(), 
    title: e.Title,
    description: e.Description
};
```

The conversion from `2014-10-21T10:00:00Z` to a number is more complex, though. The input format looks a bit like ISO-8601 plus time zone (where Z == UTC). For those, `Date.parse()` should work:

```
    date: Date.parse(e.EventDate),
```